# Return Previous Month in SSIS Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am writing an SSIS Expression that creates a Date Key to be used with a DimDate table. 
I need the Expression to return the previous Month not the Current month.

```
(DT_STR, 4,1252)YEAR(GETDATE()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) MONTH(GETDATE()),2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)  DAY( GETDATE()), 2)
```

I tried putting a -1 in the following, but it did not allow it to work.

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)  MONTH( GETDATE()-1  ),2)

RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)  MONTH( GETDATE()  )-1,2)

RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)  MONTH( GETDATE()  ),2)-1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1`

Comment: @M.Ali, I have to use the expression I listed to return a 2 Digit number for the Month. The Expression you provided will only return a 1 digit number (1 vs 01).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this when you are retrieving the Month part - 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)  MONTH( DATEADD("MONTH",-1,GETDATE()) ),2)

Answer (score 1):

```
DATEADD("Month", -1,GETDATE())
```

use code above that can make sure it comes with Year and Date also. then you can present the datetime with any format

Answer (score 0):

The SQL function (which you should be able to use here) would be something like:

`MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))`

This will return the numerical value of the previous month.

EDIT:
SSIS can be kinda funny, this should work for you:
    
    `SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,20)(DT_DBDATE) DATEADD( "mm", -1, GETDATE()), 6, 2)`

This will convert the current date minus one month into the format YYYY-MM-DD.  Then, the SUBSTRING function will grab the MM portion.  The date will always be formatted this way when using the above conversions so I hope this helps you out!

For reference:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137586(v=sql.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137586%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It still will not allow with the Overall Expression.

Comment: I just tried it by itself and it still did not allow.

Comment: If you paste the following into a query and run it you get nothing?
SELECT MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))